# ng-click no longer calls function after different dom element removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Whenever I remove a dom element that precedes an element that has a ng-click attribute specified, it will no longer call the function that the ng-click references.

Here is an example of it not working. Note: if you change if(true) to if(false) and click save it will properly call the function.

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        alert('submitted');
    }
    
    function load() {
        if(true){
            $('#resetPassword').remove();    
        }
    }
    
    load();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="btn-group m-b-20 pull-right" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="resetPassword" class="btn btn-success">Reset Password</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit();">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but you should not use jQuery. Use `ng-if` to hide or show the button on condition. That's the way to go with Angular. jQuery's `remove` here looks dirty.

Comment: Proper way to do this is to write a directive and apply that on the element you want to remove. jQuery is evil in Angular controllers.

Comment: @Jeremy If I hide/show the css doesn't work properly as it's looking for the first element in the dom, so i really need to remove it from the dom..

Comment: @Billy Can you give a link on how this would be accomplished? I'm fairly new to angularjs.

Comment: @Alex Certainly, I think the angular documentation is the most informative https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, I will post an answer aswel.

Comment: @Alex `ng-show` just show or hides, but `ng-if` _adds_ or _removes_ the element from the DOM. It's what you want, and by far the simplest solution.

Comment: @JeremyThille that worked! thank you very much. If you'd like to post it as an answer I will gladly give you credit for it.

Comment: Neat :) I just did so, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but you should not use jQuery. Use `ng-if` to add or remove the button on condition. That's the way to go with Angular. jQuery's `remove` here looks dirty. `ng-show` just show or hides, but `ng-if` *adds* or *removes* the element from the DOM. It's what you want, and by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to accomplish this with a custom directive. E.g:

**JS**

```
app.directive("removeClick", function() {
      return {   
            link:function(scope,element,attrs)
            {
                element.bind("click",function() {
                    element.remove();
                });
            }
      }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="btn-group m-b-20 pull-right" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="resetPassword"class="btn btn-success">Reset Password</button>
            <button remove-click type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit();">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You are free to use `getElementbyId` at this point, although you should probably try to pass the correct element to your directive. This will probably give you a basic understanding of angular directives.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive